# Toggle polygon layers in Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons, google-polyline

I have been struggling with this for about a month. I have done a lot of research and tried several different things but keep striking out. I have a map that contains polygons that are created with fusion tables and with data from an XML file for where the polygon needs to be plotted. It creates two different polygons. One based on polygon cords from the XML file and polygon based on a county name from the XML file using fusion tables to get the cords. I have created a drop down box with two check boxes. One Storm and One County. I am trying to set these check boxes so I can toggle the two different polygons but I am have a real hard time. I need to toggle them because sometimes the polygons will overlay each other if there are two polygons at the same location. So I need to be able to toggle between the two.

The map is located here... [GOOGLE MAP](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxsvr.php)

The code to the js for the map is here... [GOOGLE MAP CODE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/stateAlerts.js)

This is the code from the above link just for the buttons I have created....

```
//start process to set up custom drop down
        //create the check box items
        var checkOptions = {
                gmap: map,
                title: "This allows for toggling on/off Storm based polygons",
                id: "stormCheck",
                label: "Storm",
                action: function(){
                if (map.overlayMapTypes.length==0) {
                  map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
                  map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1",Polygon);
                }
                else {
                    map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
                }

            }
        }
        var check1 = new checkBox(checkOptions);

        var checkOptions2 = {
                gmap: map,
                title: "This allows for toggling on/off County based polygons",
                id: "countyCheck",
                label: "County",
                action: function(){
                if (map.overlayMapTypes.length==0) {
                  map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
                  map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1",CountyPolys);
                }
                else {
                    map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
                }

            }
}
        var check2 = new checkBox(checkOptions2);

        //create the input box items
        //possibly add a separator between controls
        var sep = new separator();

        //put them all together to create the drop down
        var ddDivOptions = {
            items: [sep, check1, check2],
            id: "myddOptsDiv"
        }
        //alert(ddDivOptions.items[1]);
        var dropDownDiv = new dropDownOptionsDiv(ddDivOptions);

        var dropDownOptions = {
                gmap: map,
                name: 'Alert Options',
                id: 'ddControl',
                title: 'Toggle storm or county based alerts',
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
                dropDown: dropDownDiv
        }

        var dropDown1 = new dropDownControl(dropDownOptions);
```

What I am having a problem with is getting these toggle boxes to toggle on and off the two different polygons layers. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I created these boxes from another example I found on here but, I am having a hard time applying these polygons to these check boxes.

Can anyone offer some suggestions or tips for what I am doing wrong or missing?

-Thanks

Comment: Look at the javascript console.  I see this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Polygon is not defined stateAlerts.js:79`

Comment: @geocodezip Yes, I am not sure how to define it or assign it to the checkboxes. It's throwing that error because that is what I tried for one of the checkboxes in the code above 'map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1",Polygon);' Which isn't right but, I am not sure which variable to use for the check boxes as I have tried many.